# How to create an empty dataframe and keep inserting data in it in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I scraped some table data from a website. The actual table on the website looks like this -

[image: Actual Table]

I used beautifulsoup to get this data which in this format -

```
[<td class="TableHeadingLeft" width="175">
                        Team
                    </td>,
 <td class="TableHeadingRight" width="35">
                        Mat
                    </td>,
 <td class="TableHeadingRight" width="35">
                        Won
                    </td>,
 <td class="TableHeadingRight" width="35">
                        Lost
                    </td>,
 <td class="TableHeadingRight" width="35">
                        Tied
                    </td>,
 <td class="TableHeadingRight" width="35">
                        N/R
                    </td>,
 <td class="TableHeadingRight" width="45">
                        Points
                    </td>,
 <td class="TableHeadingRight" width="55">
                        Net R/R
                    </td>,
 <td class="TableHeadingRight" width="75">
                        For
                    </td>,
 <td class="TableHeadingRight" width="75">
                        Against
                    </td>,
 <td align="left">
 <a class="LinkOff" href="MatchList.asp?s=2019&amp;t=MIN">Mumbai Indians</a>
 </td>,
 <td align="right">     
                        14      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        9       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        5       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        18      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        +0.421      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2380/275.1      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2282/277.2      
                    </td>,
 <td align="left">
 <a class="LinkOff" href="MatchList.asp?s=2019&amp;t=CSK">Chennai Super Kings</a>
 </td>,
 <td align="right">     
                        14      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        9       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        5       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        18      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        +0.131      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2043/274.1      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2012/274.5      
                    </td>,
 <td align="left">
 <a class="LinkOff" href="MatchList.asp?s=2019&amp;t=DDV">Delhi Capitals</a>
 </td>,
 <td align="right">     
                        14      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        9       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        5       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        18      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        +0.044      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2207/272.5      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2238/278.1      
                    </td>,
 <td align="left">
 <a class="LinkOff" href="MatchList.asp?s=2019&amp;t=SUN">Sunrisers Hyderabad</a>
 </td>,
 <td align="right">     
                        14      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        6       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        8       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        12      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        +0.577      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2288/269.2      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2200/277.5      
                    </td>,
 <td align="left">
 <a class="LinkOff" href="MatchList.asp?s=2019&amp;t=KKR">Kolkata Knight Riders</a>
 </td>,
 <td align="right">     
                        14      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        6       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        8       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        12      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        +0.028      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2466/270.4      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2419/266.2      
                    </td>,
 <td align="left">
 <a class="LinkOff" href="MatchList.asp?s=2019&amp;t=KXI">Kings XI Punjab</a>
 </td>,
 <td align="right">     
                        14      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        6       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        8       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        12      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        -0.251      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2429/276.3      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2503/277.0      
                    </td>,
 <td align="left">
 <a class="LinkOff" href="MatchList.asp?s=2019&amp;t=RRO">Rajasthan Royals</a>
 </td>,
 <td align="right">     
                        14      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        5       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        8       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        1       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        11      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        -0.449      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2153/257.0      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2192/248.2      
                    </td>,
 <td align="left">
 <a class="LinkOff" href="MatchList.asp?s=2019&amp;t=RCB">Royal Challengers Bangalore</a>
 </td>,
 <td align="right">     
                        14      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        5       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        8       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        0       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        1       
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        11      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        -0.607      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2146/258.4      
                    </td>,
 <td align="right">
                        2266/254.3      
                    </td>]
```

Now, I used a loop and some code to extract the data that I need.

```
for data in table_data.find_all('td'):
    print(''.join(data.text.split()))
```

The output of this -

```
Team
Mat
Won
Lost
Tied
N/R
Points
NetR/R
For
Against
MumbaiIndians
14
9
5
0
0
18
+0.421
2380/275.1
2282/277.2
ChennaiSuperKings
14
9
5
0
0
18
+0.131
2043/274.1
2012/274.5
DelhiCapitals
14
9
5
0
0
18
+0.044
2207/272.5
2238/278.1
SunrisersHyderabad
14
6
8
0
0
12
+0.577
2288/269.2
2200/277.5
KolkataKnightRiders
14
6
8
0
0
12
+0.028
2466/270.4
2419/266.2
KingsXIPunjab
14
6
8
0
0
12
-0.251
2429/276.3
2503/277.0
RajasthanRoyals
14
5
8
0
1
11
-0.449
2153/257.0
2192/248.2
RoyalChallengersBangalore
14
5
8
0
1
11
-0.607
2146/258.4
2266/254.3
```

Created an empty dataframe of the desired shape -

```
col_name = ['Team','Mat','Won','Lost','Tied','N/R','Points','NetR/R','For','Against']

import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=col_name)
```

Now, I couldn't able to understand, how to add these data to this dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to create a dataframe from list of list.

Code :

```
ll = []
for data in table_data.find_all('td'):
    ll.append(''.join(data.text.split()))  

n = 10
final = [ll[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(ll), n)]
col = final [0]
df = pd.DataFrame(final) 
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
df
```

`ll` is list of list from your table data.

`final` is split the `ll` with 10 columns as you mentioned in columns

The last two lines are to make the first row as column name because we just created a dataframe without giving any column names.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.concat`

```
import pandas as pd 

col_name = ['Team','Mat','Won','Lost','Tied','N/R','Points','NetR/R','For','Against']

# Main dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=col_name)

# df1 is the data frame that you want to concat in your original data frame

df = pd.concat([df, df1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the table data as 1D list

```
table_data_list = [''.join(i.text.split() for i in table_data.find_all('td')]
```

Convert the data into 2D using numpy reshape

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(table_data_list).reshape(-1,10))
```